# Structure assignment gives "expected an expression"

Tags: c, iar

I have a structure defined as

```
typedef struct sCP {
    nuint32_t Fr;
    DrRange_t DR;
    uint8_t B; 
} CP_t;
```

Some predefined values

```
#define LC4  { 86, { ( ( D5 << 4 ) | D0 ) }, 0 }
#define LC5  { 87, { ( ( D5 << 4 ) | D0 ) }, 0 }
```

and a function

```
LMS_t LMCA(uint8_t id, CP_t params)

typedef enum eLoRaMacStatus {
    LM_STATUS_OK,
    LM_STATUS_BUSY,
    LM_STATUS_PARAMETER_INVALID,
    LM_STATUS_DEVICE_OFF,
} LMS_t;
```

In the code, it is used as

```
Lmca( 3, ( CP_t )LC4 );
Lmca( 4, ( CP_t )LC5 );
```

When compiling with IAR for ARM Cortex M3, I get an `Error[Pe29]: expected an expression` on both lines.

If I do

```
CP_t t = LC4;
Lmca( 3, t );
```

This goes well, but I have the same error if I then try to call

```
t = LC5;
Lmca( 4, t );
```

Anyone has an idea how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: One's a designated-initializer-list, the other a compound literal. C++ doesn't have compound literals, AFAIK, so make sure you're compiling with a modern **C** compiler.

Comment: Does this `t = (CP_t)LC5;` work? If not then it seems the compiler does not support compound literals.

Comment: @alk same result with `t = (CP_t)LC5;`

Comment: Sry, I missed the `=`.

Comment: @alk I self corrected, but same result.

Comment: It has to work on a C99 or C11 compiler. Note: You should add the type-designator to the macros and use designated initialisers. Both improve documentation and reduce errors.

Comment: the posted snippets are (nearly) useless to us to answer your question.  Post short code that compiles and still shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the IAR compiler does not support the C99 compound literal syntax.

- either you are using it in C++ mode and this syntax is not supported as an extension
- or you are using it in pre-C99 mode (with the `--c89` command line option).

Comment: This is C code embedded with cpp code. GNU G++ compile the code, while IAR doesn't. 

IAR can compile this in C project (C99).

I'm wondering how to overcome this, as I plan to support several toolchain with the same code base.

Comment: @mirmit: You cannot "embed C code with C++ code". Either you compile as C++ or C. They are distinct languages, each with unique features and semantics.